# How to extract tags from HTML file and write them to a new file?

Tags: python, html, regex

My HTML file has the format shown below

```
<unit id="2" status="FINISHED" type="pe">

    <S producer="Alice_EN">CHAPTER I Down the Rabbit-Hole</S>

    <MT producer="ALICE_GG">CAPÍTULO I Abaixo do buraco de coelho</MT>

    <annotations revisions="1">

     <annotation r="1">
    

<PE producer="A1.ALICE_GG"><html>
 <head>

 </head>
 <body>
   CAPÍTULO I Descendo pela toca do coelho
  </body>
</html></PE>
```

I need to extract ALL the content from two tags in the entire HTML file. The content of one of the tags that starts with <unit id ...> is in one line, but the content of the other tag that starts with "<PE producer ..." and ends with '' is spread over different lines. I need to extract the content within these two tags and write the content to a new file one after another. My output should be:

```
<unit id="2" status="FINISHED" type="pe">

<PE producer="A1.ALICE_GG"><html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
  CAPÍTULO I Descendo pela toca do coelho
</body>
</html></PE>
```

My code does not extract the content from all the tags of the file. Does anyone have a clue of whats is going on and how I can make this code work properly?

```
import codecs
import re

t=codecs.open('ALICE.per1_replaced.html','r')

t=t.read()


unitid=re.findall('<unit.*?"pe">', t)
PE=re.findall('<PE.*?</PE>', t, re.DOTALL)



for i in unitid:
    for j in PE:
        a=i + '\n' + j + '\n'
    with open('PEtags.txt','w') as fi:
        fi.write(a)
```

Comment: Ok, you re-write the `a` value in the loop. You need `a = []` before the loop, then use `a.append(i + '\n' + j)` (instead of `a=i + '\n' + j + '\n'`) and then `fi.write('\n'.join(a))`

Comment: I want to loop throughout the list assigned to the variables unitid and PE and write the items of both lists to a file one after another.

Comment: Ok, then why concat them at all? `with open('PEtags.txt','w') as fi: fi.write("{}\n",format('\n'.join(unitid))); fi.write('\n'.join(PE));`

Comment: I think there is also a problem with the regular expression that tries to find the content between <PE ...</PE>

Comment: [Looks fine to me](https://regex101.com/r/L1EMwV/1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a problem with the code where you loop through the matches and write them to file.

If your `initid` and `PE` match counts are the same, you may adjust the code to

```py
import re

with open('ALICE.per1_replaced.html','r') as t:
  contents = t.read()
  unitid=re.findall('<unit.*?"pe">', contents)
  PE=re.findall('<PE.*?</PE>', contents, re.DOTALL)
  with open('PEtags.txt','w') as fi:
    for i, p in zip(unitid, PE):
      fi.write( "{}\n{}\n".format(i, p) )
```

Comment: that's very good, but I need to write to a file tag "unitid" before the tag "PE" one after another: unitid > PE (newline) unitid > PE (newline) unitid > PE (newline) and so on...

Comment: @NataliaResende Do you want to say their number is always the same? If there are 4 PEs, there are always 4 "unitid"s? Then use `for i, p in zip(unitid, PE): fi.write( "{}\n{}\n".format(i, p) )`

Comment: yes, for each PE tag there is a unit ID. They are like pairs of tags...tag PE contains a sentence and tag unit ID contains the ID of that sentence. That's why I need the tag unit ID before each tag PE.